# Searching the word in a list with more a's

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with an assignment a teacher made. I'm a python newbie so I don't really understand the language.

I need to create a function that given a string of words and looks for the word with more "a" on it and if there are two words with the same number of "a" prints the first one.

Edit 1:
Yes well my idea was to look at each word and use something like `str.count("a")` and then print the word with the highest value

Comment: A great starting point for getting help is showing what you've thought about so far...any chance you can walk us through how you'd do it manually?

Comment: @Downvoter: no this isn't a good question, but instead of just downvoting the new guy into oblivion why don't you give him a chance to edit?

Comment: do you have any ideas?  That's why I said, "Manually" what would you if you were going to do this on a piece of paper, with a pencil?

Comment: Yes well my idea was to look at each word and use something like str.count("a") and then print the word with the highest value

Comment: Alright! That sounds like a great start. How do you do something to each value in a collection?

Comment: something like :
if "a" in list ?

Comment: for a in list:
   if a.count("a")

something like this? i don't really understand the for operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should be pretty simple, even for beginners, because it uses only very basic commands:

```
s = 'caaat caat cat kittycaat, rack, smaaack'
x = 0
for i in s.split():
    if i.count('a') > x:
        x = i.count('a')
        word = i
print word
```

Basically, it uses the .split() function of a string to split the string into separate words. Then the for loop goes through each word, noting how many 'a''s there are in each word and if there are more than x words, it updates x with the number and puts the word in the 'word' variable.

When the loop gets another word with more 'a''s, then it will updates x again and word again, but if it gets a word with less 'a''s, then it will do nothing.

Comment: Wow thanks that's really easy to understand!! I don't really understand the z letter why using it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I coped the wrong code from IDLE. That z should be "s.split()", I fixed it in the answer. Do you understand how the code works now? Christopher explained a good deal of it. Btw, the split returns a list of words and the "i" in the code is basically each element of that list ie. a word.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> words = "foo bar baz banana"
>>> max(words.split(), key=lambda x:x.count("a"))
'banana'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tryed your solution and it works! But I don't understand the lambda method maybe I will do it in future assignments. But thanks!